# What are the various HttpClient flavors I can try which can execute the url and get response as String?

Tags: java, performance, httpclient, resttemplate

I have a very simple requirement -  I need to execute an URL and get the data back as string and then return this string as it is. As of now I am using `RestTemplate` to make the call as I need to pass header value as well to my service url.

Below is my example on RestTemplate which I am using so far. I am using RestTemplate in multitreaded environment. The project in which I am using the below code is very performance critical so that's why we are not doing any deserialization of JSON string, we just return back the string as it is which we get from the server.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headerInfo = new HttpHeaders();
headerInfo.add("Client-Context", "some-value");
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(headerInfo);

String response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
// return this  response back to customer
```

What are the other alternatives I can try instead of using RestTemplate which will be faster and efficient as compared to RestTemplate? I am thinking performance might be same as compared to other HttpClient but still I want to try it out on my end to see what is the difference coming up in the performance.

Any example with the alternative solution will help me as well.

Comment: I wish someone has told me this so i am sharing what i know now with you - there are plenty of plugins that will take care of all network calls for you - here are few: Volley (was presented at the Google I/O 2013), Retrofit, EventBus, etc. I would vote to unblock this question as I think this info needs to be more wide spread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). It offers thread pooling and some features that make things easier out of the box. It may not be any more performant than what you're using now but you can test that to be sure. It would look something like this (`httpClient` is an implementation of [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) that you decide on and configure):

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("some-url");
request.addHeader("Client-Context", "some-value");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
return IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
```

You could also just use [Java URLs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), which is more barebones:

```
URL url = new URL("some-url");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Client-Context", "some-value");
return IOUtils.toString(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

Of course with both of the above examples, you'll need to decide how to handle exceptions and convert the `InputStream` to a `String` (`IOUtils.toString()` is one option).